# Remove dependent Task of another Task?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a build.gradle file where I use the Java plugin and I have two custom tasks.

```
task first(...) {
}

task second(...) {
  dependsOn('compileJava')
}
```

I want that the `compileJava`task of the Java plugin depends on my `first`task.I know I can do that with:

```
tasks.compileJava.dependsOn += first
```

When I run my `second` task I want that the `compileJava` task does not dependsOn the `first` task.

**How can I remove the dependsOn first from the compileJava task only when task `second`runs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `project.gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames()` will returns the names of the tasks to execute in this build. Then you can use the returned value in order to condition the statement `tasks.compileJava.dependsOn += first` on whether the list of tasks to execute contain the task `second`, i.e.:

```
    if (project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("second")) {
        tasks.compileJava.dependsOn += first
    }
```